# Css sprites and positioning

Tags: css, compass-sass, sprite

I am using the awesome [compass style](http://compass-style.org/) to generate sprites for my style sheets. I can generate sprites and use them as backgrounds, which is all working fine.

The problem is that previously I have used `background-position` to position my backgrounds within an element.

For example here's one:

```
background: left bottom url('../images/bottom-bg.png) no-repeat;
```

The height of the containing element is variable, and this places the background on the bottom and works beautifully.

However, if I switch to compass sprites and use `@extend .system-bottom-bg;`, the `background-position` property is used to grab the appropriate position of the image from the sprite map.

In such a case, how can I use css sprites and still be able to position the background on the bottom of an element?

Comment: As Compass is being used, I am not sure how one would go about jsfiddling it.

Comment: how would anyone can see the real problem with just lines explaining situation, it would be nice if we can see something like working link to encounter the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research, it seems that due to the limitations of `background-position`, this is not possible. A decent list of shortfalls with CSS sprites is outlined here: http://www.onderhond.com/blog/work/css-sprites-pros-and-cons.

As `background-position` is used to to define the position an image occupies in a sprite sheet, we can't use it to define how that portion of the sprite sheet will appear on the page. The article linked above offers some solutions that may be implemented in the future.

One possible solution is to put the image as the last item in the sprite sheet, and then insert a huge amount of space between this image and the previous image. Obviously this is not a very neat solution, but given that compass does not allow us to set the position of images within a sprite sheet, this is not possible anyway.

My solution was to change my markup so that setting `background-position: left bottom` is not required, and I can just set the sprite image as the background image.